# PHP renaming/chaning featured picture

Tags: php, image, rename

I'm trying to make a PHP script that changes the featured picture of some item.
The general principle is that it when $_POST['featured'] is set, it renames that picture to featured.jpg and renames all other pictures to their hash_file value. However, it works well the first time when there is no featured picture set, but when I try to change it from one featured picture to another, the previous featured picture gets removed and the new one doesn't get renamed to featured.jpg. All pictures are in the same folder.

Here is the relevant code:

```
if (isset($_POST['featured'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $slike = glob('../img/uploads/'.$id.'/*.{jpg,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
    if ($slike != null) {
        foreach ($slike as $slika) {
            $path = realpath($slika);
            $name = basename($path);
            if($name == basename($_POST['featured'])){
                if(!file_exists(dirname($path) . '/featured.jpg')){
                    rename($path, dirname($path) . '/featured.jpg');
                }else{
                    rename(dirname($path) . '/featured.jpg', dirname($path) . '/' . hash_file('md5', $path) . '.jpg');
                    rename($path, dirname($path) . '/featured.jpg');
                }
            }else{
                rename ($path, dirname($path) . '/' . hash_file('md5', $path) . '.jpg');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you renaming all images like this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to accomplish having one featured picture named featured.jpg and others having their hash_file value. The featured.jpg picture is then used as a featured picture of that item. Renaming others to their hash_file value is just to make sure there are no duplicates and so the file names aren't messy, since they are uploaded by the user.

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is right here: `rename($path, ` Change the `$path` argument to point to the image you want to rename.

Comment: I think $path is already the image I want to rename. Path is defined in the foreach loop as $path = realpath($slika).

Comment: Solved by simply using a database for storing the name of the featured picture. Probably should've done this at first, but I didn't want to query the database for what I thought was such a trivial thing to do.